# Is there a max size of samples that tensorflow Datasets can hold?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow-datasets

I have a few questions regarding [tensorflow Datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset).

I've created a tensorflow dataset object in a jupyter notebook, a training data set holding 3.7 million samples and a test set holding close to 1 million samples.
Each sample is a time series of 1000 values.

For both the train and test set I did

```
dataset = dataset.cache()
dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(dataset))
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

The creation of these cells of the notebook are executed splendidly.
But right in the next cell, when I want to enumerate through the test data set, my jupyter kernel connection breaks (also described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1706). The debug output revealed this problem:

```
tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:80] Allocation of 18936000000 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
```

This issue is also [described here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18736).
I've already got the batch_size down to 1, I enabled

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

but I still have this problem. My machine has 64GBs of RAM and 6GB of GPU memory.

My questions are:

1. Is there a limit to how many samples tensorflow datasets can hold?
2. I could decrease the time series length down further, but would this even help if there is such a limit?
3. Is there any intelligent idea/way (or other more efficient data structure) to not run into this memory error?
4. Is this the GPU memory or the RAM memory that is exceeded?

Sorry for this whole bunch of questions, Im learning and Im grateful for anything.

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same problem with a large dataset of time series based data. In fact my debugger does not output any error message at all, it only shows that the jupyter kernel collapsed. I exported the code to a regular py file and executed the script but python just exits without any warning or error message. I reduced batch size to 1 and that does not help either. Gpu workload "Cuda" spikes for a moment and then the code exits without any error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're overloading the memory is that you're fitting all of it in memory when you `cache()` and set the `shuffle()` buffer to be the entire dataset. If you remove the former and massively decrease the shuffle buffer it should help.

> tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:80] Allocation of 18936000000 exceeds 10% of free system memory.

It's the CPU

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas Gervais for your answer! I removed the `cache()` and massively decreased the shuffle buffer from `len(dataset)` down to `10`, but still I have the problem `Allocation of 18936000000 exceeds 10% of free system memory.` Any other ideas? Please bear with me

Comment: BTW, is there a way for TF to use more than 10% of the memory?

Comment: Well what you got was a warning, not an error, so it should be working despite this warning

Comment: Not quite: "But right in the next cell, when I want to enumerate through the test data set, my jupyter kernel connection breaks (also described here." 
So everytime I want to enumerate through the dataset, the kernel breaks and the notebook freezes. When I look in the debug output, I see forementioned allocation issue. 
Maybe this happens because of my enumerate - does `enumerate(dataset)` cause this memory overflow?